# Avoid array overrwriting

Tags: java, arrays

I have this piece of code, within my `Main` method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            double psd = JMath.sqrt((((4*cc)/(JMath.pow((1 + 6*frequency[i]*cc), (double) 5/3)))*df));              
            double cohC = H*JMath.sqrt((frequency[i]/A.averageHubWindSpeed)*(frequency[i]/A.averageHubWindSpeed) + (.12/Lc)*(.12/Lc));          
            BLAS.getInstance().sscal(packDistance.length, (float) cohC,packDistance, 1);    
}
```

This way `packDistance` is overwritten, so for `i == 1`, `sscal` will multiply **cohC** with the **packDistance** stemming from the `sscal` at `i == 0`. Instead, I want `packDistance` to hold the same original values, which are assigned outside the loop.

How could I overtake this issue?

Comment: Use a copy of the array made before the loop.

Comment: Well, copy the array to another before entering the for loop and use that copy. Look at [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Comment: Put that array assignment statement inside the loop.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I am unable to understand what you're trying to do. A more complete ([self-contained](http://sscce.org/#selfcon)) code sample and explanation with examples of desired value and actual value always helps. And your code seems unnecessarily complicated to reproduce the problem - you surely could've replaced the two equations with something a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java's [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) method as follows :

```
T[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(packDistance,packDistance.length);
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            double psd = JMath.sqrt((((4*cc)/(JMath.pow((1 + 6*frequency[i]*cc), (double) 5/3)))*df));              
            double cohC = H*JMath.sqrt((frequency[i]/A.averageHubWindSpeed)*(frequency[i]/A.averageHubWindSpeed) + (.12/Lc)*(.12/Lc));          
            BLAS.getInstance().sscal(packDistance.length, (float) cohC,packDistance, 1);    
}
```

where T is the data type of the array you are trying to copy. Here is an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/ArrayCopyDemo.java) of usage of Arrays.copyOf().